# Getting coordinate / shape data from pydot for layout in PyQt4

Tags: pyqt4, graphviz, pydot

I would like to use the QGraphicsView control and QGraphicsScene to layout GraphViz generated graphs using pydot.  Is there a way to generate the graph in pydot, have GraphViz do the layout, and then extract the layout information (such as is included in the various output formats generated by pydot.write_xyz)?  So far in my testing the get_pos() functions for Nodes, etc. return None.

Answer (score 2):

As you already said, you have to first output the graph with `create_dot` to a string, then generate the graph layout by passing that string to `graph_from_dot_data`:

```
graphWithPositions = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(graph.create_dot())
```